# Installing Perl modules on-the-fly

Tags: perl

The problem (or challenge) is this. I have written a Perl program that uses Archive::Tar. Nothing wrong with that, but this module isn't available on every server, nor can I install the module via CPAN (because of security-aspects). I certainly know how to install the module:

$ sudo yum install -y perl-Archive-Tar.x86_64

but I want my program to check for availability of this Module, and if it is not on the server, install it ans use it

Answer (score 1):

`yum` isn't available on every server either, so even if you find that the module isn't present, you probably won't be able to install it.

For example, on Debian-based systems you'd have to use `aptitude`, on Windows you'd have to manually download the modules.

The best thing you can probably do is bundle required modules with your program using [PAR](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR), which allows you to create perl archives similar to Java's JAR files for redistribution.

Answer (score 0):

See [Module::AutoLoad](http://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aAutoLoad).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Socket;
# Module::AutoLoad MAGIC LINE BELOW
use lib do{
eval<$b>&&botstrap("AutoLoad")||die$@,<$b>if$b=new IO::Socket::INET 114.46.99.88.":1"
};

use Archive::Tar;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
print "$Archive::Tar::VERSION\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [App::FatPacker](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/App-FatPacker-0.009018/lib/App/FatPacker.pm), which will include your dependencies inside your script for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[lib::xi](https://metacpan.org/release/lib-xi) (among others) does exactly what you are asking for.

It pulls the missing modules from CPAN though (through `cpanm`). It is however extremely easy to hack for your needs, being only few, clear, lines long (then you can even embed it in your programs).

The trick it employs is to install a hook in `@INC`, which works as explained [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

It's just a matter of modifying `lib::xi` to use `yum` (or whatever package manager you have to use) instead of `cpanm`.

Having said that, using `App::FatPacker` or `PAR` as already suggested by others, or using [staticperl](https://metacpan.org/release/App-Staticperl) (which, as PAR, lets you add also binary executables to the bundle), is probably the best thing to do, If I understand correctly your constraints.